# Merge two filters in kibana3/elastic.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I have two filters in my custom panel in Kibana3:

```
 request = request.query(
    $scope.ejs.FilteredQuery(
       boolQuery,
       filterSrv.getBoolFilter(filterSrv.ids())  // has to be merged with BoolFilter2
     ))
     .size($scope.panel.size);
```

This works for either of the two filters but I want to filter with the two objects but I dont know how to merge them. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know how the javascript logic works, but my suggestion would be the And filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana 3 filters can be set to the "either" mode instead of "must".

This translates into filters that look like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fquery": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "test1"
              }
            },
            "_cache": true
          }
        },
        {
          "fquery": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "test2"
              }
            },
            "_cache": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the filterSrv code that handles that in Kibana 3: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/3.0/src/app/services/filterSrv.js#L144

```
this.getBoolFilter = function(ids) {
  var bool = ejs.BoolFilter();
  // there is no way to introspect the BoolFilter and find out if it has a filter. We must keep note.
  var added_a_filter = false;

  _.each(ids,function(id) {
    if(dashboard.current.services.filter.list[id].active) {
      added_a_filter = true;

      switch(dashboard.current.services.filter.list[id].mandate)
      {
      case 'mustNot':
        bool.mustNot(self.getEjsObj(id));
        break;
      case 'either':
        bool.should(self.getEjsObj(id));
        break;
      default:
        bool.must(self.getEjsObj(id));
      }
    }
  });
  // add a match filter so we'd get some data
  if (!added_a_filter) {
    bool.must(ejs.MatchAllFilter());
  }
  return bool;
};

this.getEjsObj = function(id) {
  return self.toEjsObj(dashboard.current.services.filter.list[id]);
};
```

You could modify that function to take an optional argument that sets the mandate to either.